# I need help understanding parent/child relationships in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, parent-child

I am writing some game design tutorials for a high school class I teach and keep getting stuck on the same issue in several different files I'm using to teach and learn.

The error (and I did search this) is the 2025 "must be a child of the caller" error. To understand this better, I created a file as follows. I'll qualify by noting that this is a .fla based frame code, where the other work we do is in an .as file. At any rate:

```
fireButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fire_fn);
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveShots);

var speed:int = 20;
var shot:Shot;
var shots:Array=new Array;

function fire_fn(e:Event) {
    shot = new Shot();
    shot.x = gun.x+shot.width;
    shot.y = gun.y;
    addChild(shot);
    shots.push(shot);
}

function moveShots(e:Event) {
    for(var i:int=shots.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        shots[i].x += speed;
        if(shots[i].x > stage.stageWidth -50) {
           removeChild(shots[i]);
        }
       }
}
```

I know the issue rests in the line removeChild, but I'm not clear as to how that should be written or (possibly more importantly) why. Any input is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not removing the shot from the array. So the next time through the loop, the condition will be met again, but the shot will have already been removed. You need to splice the shot from the shots Array;

Try this :

```
function moveShots(e:Event) {
    for(var i:int=shots.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        shots[i].x += speed;
        if(shots[i].x > stage.stageWidth -50) {
           removeChild(shots[i]);
           shots.splice(i,1);
        }
       }
}
```

Comment: This worked! And, I believe, solved problems I've been having in developing a more engaging game design for my students to create. Thanks!

Comment: Great, if you need more help, let me know. My email is in my profile and I do offer tutoring.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should do some error handling. To remove a child from a parent, the child must actually be a child of that parent. The state cannot take a kidnapped child away from its actual parents, only the kidnapper (horrible analogy, but it makes sense).

So...

```
if ( shots[i] is DisplayObject && ( shots[i] as DisplayObject ).parent == this ) {
    this.removeChild( shots[i] );
}
```

That will ensure the child is actually a DisplayObject and that its parent is what you are about to remove it from. This is not what is actually causing your problem though. After you remove a child, you also need to remove it from your array.

```
if ( shots[i] is DisplayObject && ( shots[i] as DisplayObject ).parent == this ) {
    this.removeChild( shots[i] );
    shots.splice( i, 1 );
}
```

Comment: His loop is already going in reverse, so `i--` is not needed. If it was counting upwards, that would be needed. In this case, `i--` would actually cause an object to be skipped.

Comment: @prototypical Woops. Good catch. I rarely write loops that go backward so I never think to check if other developers do it. I'll update my answer. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: I tend to go forwards for things like this as well. Also wanted to note that while checking to see if a DisplayObject has the expected parent can have value so long as there is a good reason why it might not. But in a case like this, it can also help a bug evade you. If one of your shots is not on the display list, yet is an element of your array, that's a problem I'd probably want to know about. Usually a symptom of a much larger problem.

Comment: While the array issue above took care of me, I'll be exploring this solution as well to learn more and understand how this works.  Aah--I just got it. I tried only the part you have in the first code section, and still got errors. Adding the splice closes the deal. I was also using another test that, while giving me info (parent was root1), was causing another error. Took that out and now this works as well. Thanks!